# Problems setting up Detox for E2E tests in a Expo React Native managed app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, e2e-testing, detox

I'm trying to integrate E2E tests with my Expo React Native managed app but I have not been able to do so successfully yet. I'd like to be able to run E2E tests locally and that's why I'm building the app locally and then have Detox install it together with the test runner on my Android device (not emulator), but it won't start.

I get the following error after the app and the test runner get installed:

```
Failed to run application on the device

    HINT: Most likely, your main activity has crashed prematurely.

    Native stacktrace dump:
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not launch intent Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x14000000 cmp=com.nockwellness.dev/.MainActivity (has extras) } within 45000 milliseconds. Perhaps the main thread has not gone idle within a reasonable amount of time? There could be an animation or something constantly repainting the screen. Or the activity is doing network calls on creation? See the threaddump logs. For your reference the last time the event queue was idle before your activity launch request was 1683578221739 and now the last time the queue went idle was: 1683578221739. If these numbers are the same your activity might be hogging the event queue.
```

My process has been as follows:

1. Build the app using `eas build -e test -p android --local`. This creates two .apk files, one is the actual app and the other one is the test runner I think. The config I have set up for this profile in eas.json is below:

```
{
  ...
  "build": {
    ...
    "test": {
            "distribution": "internal",
            "channel": "staging",
            "android": {
                "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease :app:assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=release",
                "withoutCredentials": true
            },
            "ios": {
                "simulator": true
            },
            "env": {
                "CHANNEL": "staging"
            }
        },
    ...
    }
  ...
}
```

2. Extract the tar.gz produced by the command mentioned above which results in adding the following paths at my project root to the mentioned .apk files: a) `androidTest/release/app-release-androidTest.apk`; b) `release/app-release.apk`.
3. Run `detox test --configuration android.attached.release`. The configuration file I'm using is below:

```
{
    logger: {
        level: process.env.CI ? 'debug' : undefined,
    },
    testRunner: {
        args: {
            $0: 'jest',
            config: 'e2e/jest.config.js',
        },
        jest: {
            setupTimeout: 120000,
        },
    },
    artifacts: {
        plugins: {
            log: process.env.CI ? 'failing' : undefined,
            screenshot: 'failing',
        },
    },
    apps: {
        'android.release': {
            type: 'android.apk',
            build: 'cd android && ./gradlew :app:assembleRelease :app:assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=release && cd ..',
            binaryPath: 'release/app-release.apk',
            testBinaryPath: 'androidTest/release/app-release-androidTest.apk',
        },
    },
    devices: {
        attached: {
            type: 'android.attached',
            device: {
                adbName: '.*',
            },
        },
    },
    configurations: {
        'android.attached.release': {
            device: 'attached',
            app: 'android.release',
        },
    },
};
```

All of this results in the "Failed to run application on the device" error mentioned above. As I said, after this process is done the apps actually get installed on my device and function properly but Detox can't open it and I don't know why. Right after they get installed nothing happens, my device keeps still and it's like nothing is happening when the app should be at leasst trying to launch.